# Error while trying to run a release build of a Qt application on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, entry-point

I'm trying to build the Windows version of my app. The program compiles and runs fine on Qt Creator but when I try to run it standalone it throws the following error:

```
The procedure entry point _Z17qt_message_output9QtMsgTypePKc could not be located in the dynamic link library QtCore4.dll
```

I have all the necessary dlls in my application folder and they are the same ones that came with the binaries I've downloaded from the Qt's website. This error is driving me crazy for I can't seem to find any reason for it. The application runs fine on Linux and MAC OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. I was copying the wrosng dll (not sure why Qt ships with 2 different versions).

The right ones are in:C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\bin and **NOT** in C:\Qt\2010.05\bin

I hope this helps anyone who might stumble upon this issue.

Comment: in version 4.7.3, there's only one "bin" folder with Qtcore4.dll inside. I don't know how to fix this?