# Qt Release build giving MSVC++ Runtime Library Error

Tags: c++, qt, build, mingw, runtime-error

I have a perfectly working application (exe with around 16 DLLs) when building in Debug mode. However, as soon as I switch to Release, get the exe and all DLLs built, all required DLLs copied over from the QtSDK bin, I'm getting a runtime error.

How exactly am I supposed to troubleshoot what's happening? Is this a common issue? I don't get any entry points, etc., to even start from.. just a generic runtime error.

The only similar question I've found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361584/error-while-trying-to-run-a-release-build-of-a-qt-application-on-windows), but this is from a much older version of Qt. 4.7.4 only has one bin folder.

**Edit 1** - I've commented everything out of my main.cpp except creating my MainWindow object, and everything out of my MainWindow constructor, so it should just be opening an empty window - still the Runtime Library issue.

[image]

Note - Keeping it in release mode and starting the debugger launches the application fine. 
Debug -> Start and Debug External Application also results in this Runtime Library error.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation, I never knew that. Now any advice on fixing this? :)

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Visual Studio/C++ or something else?

Comment: Qt c++, using Mingw for the compiler.

Comment: Thanks.  If it was MSVC I was going to say use the debugger to attach to the process while it was running.  If you can do that with Qt c++, that would allow you at least see the call stack while the dialog is being displayed.  Might help you narrow down which method your code is calling.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was hoping to do, but unfortunately the error occurs as soon as the exe is launched (no window even opens). I can have Qt launch the exe externally and attach, but the library error fires before Qt even logs anything.

Comment: In MSVC you can debug EXE that contain no debug information(compiled for release) using this technique you only see disassembly window or even create debug information for EXE and DLL that compiled for release in a separate file(called pdb or program database) and use it to debug your release EXE with even seeing its source code. But while you are using Mingw another option is to create a log file at entry point and start logging to that file as soon as program start and hope to find the function that cause the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies everyone. It appears the QtSingleApplication libraries aren't working correctly. I had implemented this to force any files I open to open into the one instance. I've recompiled it and it still isn't working, but just using a QApplication seems to have resolved the Runtime Library. I'll have to look into the QtSingleApplication a bit more and see why it's being a pain.

Thanks for the quick comments regardless :)

Comment: Hi DavidJ, How is your project. I get error similar your error. Do you have any solution for fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Add also libEGL.dll.

See this bug for details: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28766